# How to get exception context for a manually raised exception in PL/pgSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, plpgsql, error-handling, exception

In Postgres, we get the "stack trace" of exceptions using this code:

```sql
EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
    GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS v_error_stack = PG_EXCEPTION_CONTEXT;
```

This works fine for "natural" exceptions, but if we raise an exception using

```sql
RAISE EXCEPTION 'This is an error!';
```

...then there is no stack trace. According to a [mailing list entry](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAFj8pRDtD8nREykkfj7WXgupUOkW-Q7ESr=GujTZDCr9Q+AkrQ@mail.gmail.com), this might be intentional, although I can't for the life of me figure out why. It makes me want to figure out another way to throw an exception other than using `RAISE`. Am I just missing something obvious? Does anyone have a trick for this? Is there an exception I can get Postgres to throw that would contain a string of my choosing, so that I would get not only my string in the error message, but the full stack trace as well?

Here's a full example:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION error_test() RETURNS json AS $$
DECLARE
    v_error_stack text;
BEGIN

    -- Comment this out to see how a "normal" exception will give you the stack trace
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'This exception will not get a stack trace';

    -- This will give a divide by zero error, complete with stack trace
    SELECT 1/0;

-- In case of any exception, wrap it in error object and send it back as json
EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN

    -- If the exception we're catching is one that Postgres threw,
    -- like a divide by zero error, then this will get the full
    -- stack trace of the place where the exception was thrown.
    -- However, since we are catching an exception we raised manually
    -- using RAISE EXCEPTION, there is no context/stack trace!
    GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS v_error_stack = PG_EXCEPTION_CONTEXT;

    RAISE WARNING 'The stack trace of the error is: "%"', v_error_stack;

    return to_json(v_error_stack);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to show a simple example here.

Comment: Good point @CraigRinger. Done!

Comment: It's not self-contained. What's `error_info`? Looks like a custom type.

Comment: Sorry - thought you just wanted general context. I've removed the extraneous stuff.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This behaviour appears to be by design.

In `src/pl/plpgsql/src/pl_exec.c` the error context callback explicitly checks to see if it's being called in the context of a PL/PgSQL `RAISE` statement and, if so, skips emitting the error context:

```
/*
 * error context callback to let us supply a call-stack traceback
 */
static void
plpgsql_exec_error_callback(void *arg)
{
        PLpgSQL_execstate *estate = (PLpgSQL_execstate *) arg;

        /* if we are doing RAISE, don't report its location */
        if (estate->err_text == raise_skip_msg)
                return;
```

I can't find any specific reference as to *why* that is the case.

Internally in the server, the context stack is generated by processing the `error_context_stack`, which is a chained callback that appends information to a list when called.

When PL/PgSQL enters a function it adds an item to the error context callback stack. When it leaves a function it removes an item from that stack.

If the PostgreSQL server's error reporting functions, like `ereport` or `elog` are called, it calls the error context callback. But in PL/PgSQL if it notices that it's being called from a `RAISE` its callbacks intentionally do nothing.

Given that, I don't see any way to achieve what you want without patching PostgreSQL. I suggest posting mail to pgsql-general asking why `RAISE` doesn't provide the error context now that PL/PgSQL has `GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS` to make use of it.

(BTW, the exception context is not a stack trace as such. It looks a bit like one because PL/PgSQL adds each function call to the stack, but it's also used for other details in the server.)

Comment: Thank you very much Craig for the quick and thorough answer. It does seem odd to me, and certainly counter to my expectations. The usefulness of `RAISE` is diminished by that check. I'll write to them.

Comment: @Taytay Please include a link to your question here, but do make sure your mail is complete and can be understood *without* following the link; many people ignore link-only or link-mostly posts. If you get the chance to pop a link to your post in the comments here, via http://archives.postgresql.org/ that'd be really awesome to help other people later.

Comment: Thanks Craig. Good advice. I created a thread here: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1427953375873-5844382.post@n5.nabble.com  As of now, they're looking for a good solution to the issue.

Answer (score 8):

You can **work around this restriction** and make plpgsql emit **error context** as desired by calling another function that raises (warning, notice, ...) the error for you.

I posted a solution for that a couple of years back - [in one of my first posts here on dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7214/generate-an-exception-with-a-context/7598#7598):

```
-- helper function to raise an exception with CONTEXT
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_raise(_lvl text = 'EXCEPTION'
                                  ,_msg text = 'Default error msg.')
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
BEGIN
   CASE upper(_lvl)
      WHEN 'EXCEPTION' THEN RAISE EXCEPTION '%', _msg;
      WHEN 'WARNING'   THEN RAISE WARNING   '%', _msg;
      WHEN 'NOTICE'    THEN RAISE NOTICE    '%', _msg;
      WHEN 'DEBUG'     THEN RAISE DEBUG     '%', _msg;
      WHEN 'LOG'       THEN RAISE LOG       '%', _msg;
      WHEN 'INFO'      THEN RAISE INFO      '%', _msg;
      ELSE RAISE EXCEPTION 'f_raise(): unexpected raise-level: "%"', _lvl;
   END CASE;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT;
```

**Details:**

- [Generate an exception with a Context](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7214/generate-an-exception-with-a-context/7598#7598)

I expanded your posted test case to demonstrate it works in Postgres 9.3:

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3fcb9/3)

Comment: Thank you so much Erwin! Funnily enough, I actually experimented with your solution before posting, but I must have done something wrong and I didn't get the context I expected. Now that I've seen the fiddle (thanks for showing me that too), I'll give it another shot!

Comment: Nicely done; it shouldn't be necessary, but looks like it'd do the trick.

Comment: @CraigRinger: Since exceptions should be, well, the *exception*, the minimal performance impact shouldn't matter, either. We have all options this way.

Comment: Totally agree, I'd just like to see the need for the workaround go away at some point.

Comment: @CraigRinger: True. If that's not going to happen any time soon, we might suggest this workaround in the manual ...